# System androideabi not recognized while building libtool-2.2.4

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, porting, configure

while trying to build libtool(2.2.4) for android i get:

> Downloads/android-ndk-r10/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/ and cc
>   understand -c and -o together... yes checking how to run the C
>   preprocessor...
>   /home/cdac/Downloads/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
>   --sysroot=/home/cdac/Downloads/android-ndk-r10/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/
>   -E checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnulibc1 checking host system type... Invalid configuration `arm-linux-androideabi': system`
>   androideabi' not recognized configure: error: /bin/bash
>   libltdl/config/config.sub arm-linux-androideabi failed make: *** No
>   rule to make target `clean'.  Stop. make: *** No targets specified and
>   no makefile found.  Stop.

Quick googling reveals that my config.guess & config.sub may be outdated,
tried searching on web but unable to find newer version,
so i tried to change **timestamp** variable , further applied **touch** command to these files,
still i am not able to get past the error ;;

looking at these scripts reveal that the case switch is not available for arm
so, is there a way to port the code for arm architecture ?
help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update config.guess and config.sub as you had found out. You can find new good versions at http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=tree - download them via the "raw" links on the righthand side.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you do what [mstorsjo said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25883526/895245) faster:

```
wget -O config.guess 'http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.guess;hb=HEAD'
wget -O config.sub 'http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.sub;hb=HEAD'
for f in `git ls-files | grep config.guess`; do cp config.guess "$f"; done
for f in `git ls-files | grep config.sub`; do cp config.sub "$f"; done
```